# Reportlab line plot borders

Tags: python, reportlab

Our script reads some data and generates report with line chart.
But Y-axis values could be greater than maximum value of the Y-axis, or smaller than minimum. In such cases we need to show only that part that fits in the borders. But it goes out of the borders of chart.
[image]
Is there a way to keep line plot in the borders of the plot?

```
    def add_chart(self, x, y, width, height, drawing, data, total_length):
        lc = LinePlot()
        lc.x, lc.y = x, y
        lc.width, lc.height = width, height
        lc.data = data

        lc.xValueAxis.valueMin = 0
        lc.xValueAxis.valueMax = total_length
        lc.xValueAxis.valueStep = total_length / 10
        lc.xValueAxis.labelTextFormat = seconds_to_hms
        lc.xValueAxis.labels.fontSize = 8

        lc.yValueAxis.valueMin = 0
        lc.yValueAxis.valueMax = 1500
        lc.yValueAxis.valueStep = (lc.yValueAxis.valueMax - lc.yValueAxis.valueMin) / 10
        lc.yValueAxis.visibleGrid = 1
        drawing.add(lc)
        drawing.drawOn(self.canvas, 0, 0)
```

Comment: Could you provide a code example?

Comment: @alxwrd Just updated the question.